# How can I have a cell inherit a new value after a calculation has been made?

Tags: excel

Hey guys I need a bit of help. I haven't done excel in quite a while so I am completely rusty. I am currently attempting to make an excel sheet that calculates current Employee PTO times and deducts hours used after a value has been added in a cell.

For example

I have cell "C2" with the current available PTO time an employee

Another cell "D2" which acts as time an employee used PTO time.

and a cell "E2" which acts as an "Updated Value"

I originally have "E2" as =C2-D2 to subtract the PTO time used with the current available PTO value.

would it be possible to have "C2" inherit its value with the new current available PTO value after the calculation has been made? or am I stuck with just having to manually update the value?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That would lead to a circular argument so, no. Could you just net this from the raw data?

Comment: Don't know your entire setup but it would seem more useful to have C2 = Alloted PTO, D2=Used PTO, and E2 as Available PTO. Then just manually update D2 every time PTO is used. Better yet have a sheet  (Empl. Name, Date, Hours) where an employee's history is recorded and then just have D2 as a SumIF formula to add all the used time.

Comment: Unfortunately no as I don't have access to the raw data due to our corporate offices not allowed to send raw data only figures. Ill just stick to imputing the data manually. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Single Row Solution

If you are open to a `VBA` solution you can use a `Worksheet_Change` event to move the calculation to the backend and avoid your circular reference.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D3")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Count = 1 Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("C3") = Range("C3") - Range("D3")
            Range("D3").ClearContents   'If you want to reset the Used PTO box after each use
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
End If

End Sub
```

As you update the `Used PTO` cell the `Available PTO` count will update accordingly. Note this also allows for the value to go negative

[image]

---

### Dynamic Solution

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo SafeExit

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Count = 1 Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("C" & Target.Row) = Range("C" & Target.Row) - Range("D" & Target.Row)
            Range("D" & Target.Row).ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
End If

Exit Sub

SafeExit:
Application.EnableEvents = True
MsgBox "Last Update NOT Registered", vbCritical, "Error Occured"

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much ! This definitely has helped tremendously !

Comment: Now would this be viable to use on a long list of employees? or would I have to write the VBA for each single employee ?

Comment: Assuming `Column B` would be `Employee ID/Name` you would use the same macro but adjust such that the row you are referencing is dynamic (`Target.Row`). You will also need to adjust the checks to be dynamic as well

Comment: Updated to also work on multiple rows + some needed error handling